# OpenCV 2.4 staticlib link still relies on DLL? [windows]

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, dll

My system is Windows 64bit, and I am using VS 2013. I am using the latest **OpenCV 2.4** build for Windows.

I am trying to compile a simple C program which uses **OpenCV 2.4**. The dynamic link version works well. But I need a static linked one so I think I can just copy this one executable to my working environment.

When I try to run my statically linked executable, the program cannot read my video file, but does not throw exceptions of any kind either. But if I put opencv dlls into my program's directory, the programm will work.

I have set the additional libraries path to include `opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib`. I have set the **Runtime Library** to **Multi-threaded**, but I think I still missed some option. I just could not figure it out.

Comment: You have to set the linker input directory to the static lib openCV folder (and you have to add some additional libs you might not expexpect)

Comment: @Micka, yes I did that as well

Comment: By playing with the DLLs in opencv bin folder, I found `opencv_ffmpeg2410_64.dll` is the key file. But why?

Comment: did you remove the dynmic lib directory from your linker directory? did you add any lib directory to your path- or libs- environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/56519/opencv-24-static-lib-relies-on-opencv_ffmpegdll-on-windows/)'s the question I posted on OpenCV's forum. To summarise:

```
Build your own static library from scratch.
```

### Update

*Re-post the steps from the [post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/56519/opencv-24-static-lib-relies-on-opencv_ffmpegdll-on-windows/):*

- Build static ffmpeg
- Build static opencv and static link to ffmpeg
- Build the program and static link to the opencv & ffmpeg libraries

**Caveats**: You may face **legal** issues if you statically link to the **ffmpeg** libraries.

Comment: Can you please give more explanation ? I did build it using DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS = False , now If i will add the libs they wont relay on dll's ? or I should open each module/project in visual studio and build it with special settings ?

Comment: @StavBodik, the static OpenCV libraries are *dynamically* linked to the *ffmpeg* libraries. If you need a single executable, you need to follow the steps I did on the OpenCV forum post.